# How to sort_by to get latest object using jq

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jq

So I run this:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --region xxxxxxxxx \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.VolumeId=="vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxx")'
```

And I get this https://jqplay.org/s/SnT8lDwycY

How do I sort by `StartTime` and return latest `"SnapshotId": "snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`?

When I add `| sort_by(.StartDate)'` I get below error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:22106): Cannot index string with string "StartDate"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few examples of how to use the in-built `--query` option. Each example builds on the previous one.

Get all snapshots, sorted by ascending start time:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)'
```

Get the oldest snapshot:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[0]'
```

Get the newest snapshot:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1]'

# Example of output:
{
    "Description": "End of Q3 snapshot",
    "Encrypted": false,
    "OwnerId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Progress": "100%",
    "SnapshotId": "snap-0f601234abcd12345",
    "StartTime": "2019-09-30T23:59:59.999Z",
    "State": "completed",
    "VolumeId": "vol-0f123dc5b1dd911d3",
    "VolumeSize": 8
}
```

Get the newest snapshot's ID:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].SnapshotId'

# Example of output:
"snap-0f601234abcd12345"
```

Get the newest snapshot's ID as plain text:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].SnapshotId' \
    --output text

# Example of output:
snap-0f601234abcd12345
```

If you prefer to use `jq`, you can get the same results as follows (as @peak indicated):

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx \
    | jq -r '.Snapshots | sort_by(.StartTime)[-1].SnapshotId'
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try today and report back.

Comment: Based on your examples and aws docs I came up with this. Thank you, much better answer.

`aws --region xx-xxxx-x ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxxxx --filters "Name=volume-id, Values=vol-xxxxxxxxxx" --query 'sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime)[-1].SnapshotId' --output text`

Answer (score 1):

The data shown on jqplay is a stream of JSON objects. One way to handle such a stream is to use the -s command-line option of jq.  This in effect combines them into a list, which can then be sorted.

So if you don't care about ties, a simple solution to the problem is:

```
sort_by(.StartTime) | .[-1] | .SnapshotId
```

If your jq is sufficiently up-to-date, this can be abbreviated to just:

```
sort_by(.StartTime)[-1].SnapshotId
```

Comment: Do you know how could I map or transpose this to array?

Comment: What "this" are you referring to?  What do you mean by "transpose" here?  If you simply want the result as an array, then you could enclose the entire jq expression in square brackets.  If that's not what you have in mind, then maybe you should ask a separate SO Q?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out...

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots \
    --region xx-xxxx-x  \
    --owner-ids xxxxxxxxxx \
    | jq -r '.Snapshots[] | select(.VolumeId=="vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") \
    | [(.StartTime | split(", ")), (.SnapshotId | split(", "))] \
    | transpose \
    | { Snapshots: map({ StartTime:.[0], SnapshotId:.[1] }) } \
    | .Snapshots \
    | sort_by(.StartTime) \
    | grep SnapshotId -m 1 \
    | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/"//g''
```

Comment: This seems hugely complex and fragile.

Comment: I know but I'm not that good with jq so any feedback welcomed.